# Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.9 on fresh Ubuntu install

Tags: scala, ubuntu, sbt

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04, I attempted to install and run SBT using the instructions from [www.scala-sbt.org](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html). It installed fine, but when I run it for the first time, I get a bunch of errors:

```
~$ sbt
...
:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: 
    java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
    parameter must be non-empty 
    url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.jar

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /root/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.9
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had same problem with xubuntu 15.10. I installed package ca-cacert:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-cacert
```

It solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of debugging, I found that the `cacerts` file is missing from the latest version of OpenJDK.

All I had to do was copy the `cacerts` file from `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` from a working computer to my new workstation, and it worked fine.

I've made my file available at [this link.](http://www.alanc.net/download/cacerts/cacerts.tgz)